# Angular 6 cannot resolve 'fs' and 'path' for using electron

Tags: angular, electron

I want to use ipcRenderer in the typescript of angular6 project and communicate with electron app through ipcMain.

To access ipcRenderer in typescript file:

```
this.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
this.ipcRenderer.send('data:submit', '1');
```

But when ng build for angular project, it comes with the error that

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/xxxx/Developer/angular_bootcamp/ipcStudy/node_modules/electron'
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/xxxx/Developer/angular_bootcamp/ipcStudy/node_modules/electron'
```

A lot of post mentioned that angular 6 can't use 'fs' anymore. But i need to use electron and ipcRenderer, is there anyway to solve it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Finally, i solve this issue by referencing https://dev.to/michaeljota/integrating-an-angular-cli-application-with-electron---the-ipc-4m18 and https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/337/how-to-declare-a-new-property-on-the-window-object-with-typescript.

Answer (score 5):

> Copying the answer from link given by OP:

**1-** Create a `service`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IpcRenderer } from 'electron';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IpcService {
  private ipc: IpcRenderer | undefined = void 0;

  constructor() {
    if ((window as any).require) {
      try {
        this.ipc = (window as any).require('electron').ipcRenderer;
      } catch (e) {
        throw e;
      }
    } else {
      console.warn('Electron IPC was not loaded');
    }
  }

  public on(channel: string, listener: any): void {
    if (!this.ipc) {
      return;
    }

    this.ipc.on(channel, listener);
  }

  public send(channel: string, ...args): void {
    if (!this.ipc) {
      return;
    }
    this.ipc.send(channel, ...args);
  }
}
```

**2-** Use `service` inside `component`:

```
export class TestComponent {

  constructor(private readonly ipc: IpcService) {
    this.ipc.on('my-event', (e, val) => {
      console.log('my-event: ' + val);
    });
  }

}
```

**Important Note:** While running Angular in dev mode, you'd always get the error `Electron IPC was not loaded`, for obvious reasons. But once you build the app and run it with Electron, everything will work smooth and fine.

Tested and verified with `Angular 8.1.0` and `build --prod`.

All credits to [original author](https://dev.to/michaeljota/integrating-an-angular-cli-application-with-electron---the-ipc-4m18).

Comment: Note it can also work while running Angular in dev mode. Just be sure you have electron load from `localhost` and that you have `webPreferences.nodeIntegration` set to `true`.

Answer (score -1):

I will answer because I try this solution and it works, it was hard to make it work, but then I tried another way.
I recommend used ngx-electron and it works great!! no problems involved and fast to build up.

FIRST YOU HAVE TO CREATE YOUR main.js as always. build your methods and then use ngx electron in your component. I let an example which makes me crazy for a long time and there are no working examples

first in app.module.ts

```
import { NgxElectronModule } from 'ngx-electron';

imports: [NgxElectronModule,
  FormsModule ,
  HttpClientModule ,
  BrowserModule,

  ]
```

then in your module

IN MY CASE I NEED TO IMPLEMENT SILENT PRINT

```
export class PrincipalComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('myDiv', {static: false}) myDiv: ElementRef; // reference of view i want to print

   


    constructor(
                      private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,            
                      private _electronService: ElectronService) {}
        generarPdf(){
     
      this.documento ='';
      this.imprimir = true;
      this.horario = formatDate(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm', 'en');
    
      this._electronService.ipcRenderer.send('print-to-pdf',  this.myDiv.nativeElement.innerHTML);
      this._electronService.ipcRenderer.on('wrote-pdf', function(event, path){
        this.documento ='';
        console.log('respueta recibida '+ path);
      });
    
      setTimeout(() => 
    {
        this.imprimir =  false;
    },
    3000);
    
    }
```

and in main.js

```
 ipc.on('print-to-pdf',function(event, data){
  console.log('ingreso a imprimiendo');

  win.webContents.printToPDF(pdfSettings()).then(data => {
    const pdfPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(),'./generated_pdf.pdf' );

    win.webContents.print({silent: true}, (success, errorType) => {
      if (!success){
        console.log(errorType)
      } else{
        console.log('print success');
      } 
    })

    fs.writeFile(pdfPath, data, (error) => {
      if (error) throw error
      console.log(`Wrote PDF successfully to ${pdfPath}`)
    })
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(`Failed to write PDF to ${pdfPath}: `, error)
  }) 

function pdfSettings() {
  var option = {
      landscape: false,
      marginsType: 0,
      printBackground: false,
      printSelectionOnly: false,
      
  };
return option;
}
```